# Gitlab - How to add badge based on jobs pipeline

Tags: gitlab, badge

My goal is to show badges (ex : [image]) based on pipeline results.

I have a private gitlab ce omnibus instance with the following .gitlab-ci.yml :

```
image: python:3.6

stages:
  - lint
  - test

before_script:
  - python -V
  - pip install pipenv
  - pipenv install --dev

lint:
  stage: lint
  script:
  - pipenv run pylint --output-format=text --load-plugins pylint_django project/ | tee pylint.txt
  - score=$(sed -n 's/^Your code has been rated at \([-0-9.]*\)\/.*/\1/p' pylint.txt)
  - echo "Pylint score was $score"
  - ls
  - pwd
  - pipenv run anybadge --value=$score --file=pylint.svg pylint
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - pylint.svg

test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - pipenv run python manage.py test
```

So I thought that I would store the image in the artifacts of the lint job and display it via the badge feature.

But I encounter the following issue : when I browse https://example.com/[group]/[project]/-/jobs/[ID]/artifacts/file/pylint.svg, instead of seeing the badge I have the following message :

```
The image could not be displayed because it is stored as a job artifact. You can download it instead.
```

And anyways, I feel like this is the wrong way, because even if I could get the image, there don't seems to be a way to get the image from the last job since gitlab URL for badges images only supports `%{project_path}, %{project_id}, %{default_branch}, %{commit_sha}`

So how one would add badge to a gitlab project based on a svg generated from results in a gitlab pipeline ?

My guess is that I could push to a .badge folder but that doesn't sound like a clean solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can indeed get the artifact(s) for the latest job (see documentation [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#downloading-the-latest-artifacts)), but the trick is that you need to use a slightly different URL:

`https://example.com/[group]/[project]/-/jobs/artifacts/[ref]/raw/pylint.svg?job=lint`

where `[ref]` is the reference to your branch/commit/tag.

Speaking of badge placeholders available in Gitlab, you can potentially put `%{default_branch}` or `%{commit_sha}` into `[ref]`. This won't allow you to get the correct badge for every branch, but at least your default branch will get one.

Please also note that `?job=lint` query parameter is required, without it the URL won't work.

Comment: Link to documentation is dead. Try this one: https://winf.dhsh.de/gitlab/help/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.md#downloading-the-latest-artifacts